# Send back cookie in a request

Tags: python, mechanize

I've navigated through different responses to my question but still didn't manage to run it :(.

I'm logging onto a site using python & mechanize, my code looks like this

```
    br = mechanize.Browser()

# Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
    ...
    r = br.open('http://...')
html = r.read()
    form = br.forms().next()
br.form = form
br.submit()
```

Sending the form is not a problem, the problem is that when I write br.open() again to perform a GET request, Python doesn't send back the Cookie PHPSESSID (I looked this in wireshark), any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
import cookielib, urllib2

ckjar = cookielib.MozillaCookieJar(os.path.join(’C:\Documents and Settings\tom\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\h5m61j1i.default’, ‘cookies.txt’))

req = urllib2.Request(url, postdata, header)

req.add_header(’User-Agent’, \ 
‘Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)’)

opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(ckjar) )

f = opener.open(req) 
htm = f.read() 
f.close()
```